# Test on character count

Tags: conditionals, etoolbox, xstring

I am trying to do specific actions based on the count of a certain character in a variable string.

When using the result of `StrCount` inside an `ifnumgreater`, I get an error despite the value being processed properly.

I think that the `StrCount` is not processed as an integer but it does output the correct value (after `2¿2` which appears to be an error).

Any idea of how to resolve this?

#### MWE

```
\documentclass[draft]{article}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{xstring}
\newcommand{\foo}{\StrCount{test}{t}}
\newcommand{\res}{}
\ifnumgreater{\foo}{0}{
  \renewcommand{\res}{yes}
}{\renewcommand{\res}{no}}
\begin{document}
\res
\end{document}
```

#### Output

[image: output]

#### Error log

[image: error-log]

```
./test.tex:7: Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \let 
l.7 \ifnumgreater{\foo}{2}
                          {
A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)
```

Comment: `\StrCount{test}{t}[\foo]` instead of `\newcommand`

Comment: @egreg What is the difference between `\newcommand{\foo}` and `[\foo]`. It does work but I would like to understand why.

Comment: You should look at the documentation for `xstring`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the usual problem that `\StrCount{test}{t}` is not the number 1, but a set of complex instructions that ultimately (but not expandably) produce it.

The `xstring` package allows for a trailing optional argument which should contain a control sequence that's defined to expand to the result of the operation.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{xstring}

\newcommand{\foo}{}% just for checking it's not defined
\StrCount{test}{t}[\foo]% this stores the number of matches in \foo

\newcommand{\res}{}
\ifnumgreater{\foo}{0}
  {\renewcommand{\res}{yes}}
  {\renewcommand{\res}{no}}

\begin{document}

\res

\end{document}
```

A variation using `xparse`, but the precise coding depends on information about how you plan to use the macros.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\florian}{mmmO{}}
 {% #1 = regex to test for
  % #2 = token list
  % #3 = cases
  % #4 = default
  \regex_count:nxN { #1 } { #2 } \l_florian_matches_int
  \int_case:nnF { \l_florian_matches_int } { #3 } { #4 }
 }
\int_new:N \l_florian_matches_int
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \regex_count:nnN { nx }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\testA}{test}
\newcommand{\testB}{tes}
\newcommand{\testC}{es}
\newcommand{\testD}{ttest}

\newcommand{\res}{} % initialize

\begin{document}

\florian{t}{\testA}{
 {0}{\renewcommand{\res}{no}}
 {1}{\renewcommand{\res}{yes, one}}
}[\renewcommand{\res}{yes, many}]

1. \res

\florian{t}{\testB}{
 {0}{\renewcommand{\res}{no}}
 {1}{\renewcommand{\res}{yes, one}}
}[\renewcommand{\res}{yes, many}]

2. \res

\florian{t}{\testC}{
 {0}{\renewcommand{\res}{no}}
 {1}{\renewcommand{\res}{yes, one}}
}[\renewcommand{\res}{yes, many}]

3. \res

\florian{t}{\testD}{
 {0}{\renewcommand{\res}{no}}
 {1}{\renewcommand{\res}{yes, one}}
 {3}{\renewcommand{\res}{Three!}}
}[\renewcommand{\res}{yes, many}]

4. \res

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I would like to count the number of occurrences of a specified character in a string. How can I do that with `expl3`? I have not found anything on that in the package documentation.

Comment: @Florian That wasn't specified and is quite a different problem

Comment: It is literally explained in the first sentence of my post.

Comment: @Florian Sorry, I had overlooked the first paragraph.

Comment: Your first solution covers exactly what I needed, thank you. The second one, however, is much more interesting as it allows for various use cases. It is a bit more complex though.

Comment: @Florian With more details, the second solution may be more finely tailored.

Comment: I would need to define 3 cases {0, 1, 2} just like you presented. I seem to be unable to run your example though. I get the following errors `LaTeX error: "kernel/command-not-defined"` `Control sequence \regex_count:nnN undefined.`.

Comment: @Florian You need to update your TeX distribution or to do `\usepackage{l3regex}` (the functions of this module have recently been added to the expl3 kernel).

Answer (score 1):

Tailor-made for the `listofitems` package, which provides fully expandable results.  In the MWE below, the search "sequence" can be a single character, as shown, or a multi-token sequence, such as "is" which will likewise provide `\thecharcount` of `2`.

Typically, `listofitems` is used to parse an input list for the fields between [possibly nested] separators.  Here, if we use the desired search string as the field separator, then the number of instances of the found search string (aka field separators) will be the number of fields located (known as the list length) minus 1.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listofitems}
\newcommand\countchars[2]{%
  \setsepchar{#1}%
  \readlist\mylist{#2}%
  \edef\thecharcount{\the\numexpr\listlen\mylist[]-1\relax}%
  \thecharcount
}
\begin{document}
\def\mydata{This is a test of the emergency broadcast system}
\countchars{e}{\mydata}

There are \thecharcount{} instances of the sequence ``e'' in ``\mydata''

\countchars{c}{\mydata}

There are \thecharcount{} instances of the sequence ``c'' in ``\mydata''
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

To give an example of how nested searches can be employed and utilized:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listofitems}
\begin{document}
\def\mydata{This is a test of the emergency broadcast system}
\setsepchar{e/s}
\readlist\mylist{\mydata}

There are \the\numexpr\listlen\mylist[]-1\relax{} instances of the sequence 
  ``\mylistsep[1]'' in ``\mydata''

\foreachitem\i\in\mylist{%
  \def\tlev{\mylistsep[\icnt]}%
  \def\blev{\mylistsep[\icnt,1]}%
  There are \the\numexpr\listlen\mylist[\icnt]-1\relax{} instances of ``\blev'' between 
  \ifnum\icnt=1\relax the beginning \else \tlev$_{\the\numexpr\icnt-1\relax}$ \fi and 
  \ifnum\icnt=\listlen\mylist[]\relax the end\else e$_{\icnt}$\fi.\par
}
\end{document}
```

[image]